# Traveling between worlds

Tags: magic, physics, genetics

If someone could travel between worlds that are not exactly parallel universes, or maybe not even different universes, like for example Asgard, Midgard, Hel, Alfheim, etc., would that be possible due to genetics (a trait that makes it possible) or physics (the ability - however acquired - to switch between pairs of space-time)?

Comment: Can you come up with any reason why either of those possibilities could be excluded?  You're making up the world, you make the rules.  Remember, a book about a bunch of kids that traveled to a parallel universe through a wardrobe and met lions and witches over there is a best seller.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of what would be most likely, which possibility would be more believable, but I agree with you, both could be possible. On one hand, however, I am thinking that having the ability to switch between space-time pairs would require a very advanced form of technology that the world I am building does not have access to. On the other hand, having this ability due to genetics seems highly unlikely, biologically speaking.

Comment: Check out the classic sci-fi novel, *[The Stars My Destination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination)* by Alfred Bester.  A principle plot element in the story revolves around the impact on society of personal teleportation.  The most amazing thing about the book?  It doesn't bother explaining how it works at all.  The story's good enough that the reader doesn't generally care.

Comment: Check out the novels from Dennis L McKiernan. He has multiple worlds and describes how to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genetics and physics are not mutually exclusive. Genetics is not magic; genes are just chemicals arranged in such a way that they induce cells to synthesize other chemicals (proteins) which then make the body do some things (hormones, enzimes), or get used themselves as building blocks (collagen, bone). If there's a physical mechanism to travel between worlds, it must involve physical means: some rearrangements of matter, some flows of energy. Chemical and physical laws working inside the bodies of living organisms (regulated ultimately by genes) are capable of notable things, such as turning light into energy and food, turning food back into energy, generating electrical currents of wildly varying strengths, etc.

Suppose there's a means to travel between worlds using ordinary physics (physics that is ordinary in your universe). You don't have to specify what the mechanism is, but it must be attainable through reactions (matter-energy exchanges) that can plausibly occur inside a living organism. Make it so that those reactions only take place in very particular configurations of matter, which cannot be found in inanimate matter (it being too simple) and which only certain organisms have chanced upon through genetic mutation. In our universe we have something like that: it's called self-consciousness. It's just matter interacting with itself, yet as far as we know only humans have it.

Comment: Time diver books, sorry don't remember the author.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for "most likely", the answer is most likely physics.

Genes are instructions for forming proteins and guiding the combinations of proteins into larger structures. That's it! All the sci-fi that attributes magical powers to "genes" or "Mutations" (like the series "Heroes", or the series "Zoo" which say mutations can cause telekinesis) are just trying to avoid saying it is magic, when it is. So the attribute it to something few people understand, genetics. Just like crystal power and pyramid power folk are attributing magical powers to "quantum action" and "fields".

Of course, genes can create structures that ***use*** physics; my own brain is sending electrical signals to my fingers, with precise timing and force to activate muscles that cause a physical change in the world; pressing keys to type these words. Genes formed my eyes which are reacting, by the laws of physics (which for argument's sake encompasses all of bio-electric chemistry), to form images that help guide the firing of those muscles.

But it is implausible to suggest things as large as cells are going to have any kind of ability to generate the power and precision necessary to break spacetime and do something on a macroscopic scale like move a body through another dimension.

Any ability to enter a different reality would have to be currently unknown physics. Still magic, of course, but not as dumb a handwave as "genetics." Physics can plausibly operate on a subatomic scale, focus energy, or better yet, *signal* a much larger and more powerful machine, even one powered by a star or black hole, to create a dimensional rift that would be safe to pass through. As we already know, devices can be incredibly small. So Thor can get to Asgard because some insanely advanced technology is embedded innocuously in something like a ring, medallion, armband, or in the handle of his hammer, and when he wants to open the portal this device sends a signal to Asgard which commands a planet-sized machine to create a portal he can step through.

Of course even Thor doesn't have to know how it works; his people may have found this billion year old tech left behind by aliens long ago, and learned to use it.

Comment: How about both genetics and physics?  The special sequences in the person's genes unlock a key to enable use of the "insert structure @Amadeus mentions" to signal portal creation. Simple contact with the right skin cells unlocks the technology. This still allows you to specify a certain lineage can travel between worlds if that is something you'd like to have happen.